# How to set a background color in a button of command in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

everyone! I'm not familiar with VBA, I'm using ChatGPT, but sometimes it fails. The code is

```
Sub CriarBotaoLaranja()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim btn As Button
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Worksheet1")
    
    Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(100, 100, 120, 50)
    btn.Caption = "Name in the button"
End Sub
```

Then assuming the button is designated for `btn`, I tried to pass BackColor attribute like `btn.BackColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)`, but didn't work. Thanks for every help, since now.

I made a searching in the web, and tried apply the methods there but I'm not familiar with VBA, then I don't know what happens. I ask a answer that works with my code because solutions in web worked in other codes, not in mine. When using code of ChatGPT pops up "runtime error 438. The object doesn't accept this property or method." The ChatGPT tried, then it said me to ask help in a forum.

Comment: What you are creating is called a form control button. AFAIK, you cannot change the background color of the form control button.

Comment: What you can do is, instead of a form control button, insert a shape and then change it's color. You can also assign a macro to it like you do for form control button.

Answer (score 0):

The form control button button does not have this property. But if you add a Active-X Button control you can change the Object.BackColor.

```
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CommandButton.1", Link:=False _
        , DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=201, Top:=182.25, Width:=133.5, Height _
        :=38.25).Select
   With Selection.Object
   .BackColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)
   .Caption = "Name on button"
   End With
```

Comment: What roadmap to learn VBA do you recomend? Maybe books? What? I am thankfull.

Comment: Most information on Objects is learned from examples on internet and use of places like this site or just Google it. Another tips is to mark code in VBA and press F1(help) . That will get you to Microsoft page of the object and explained how to use it. But if you are quite new to programming vba for dummies is a good place to start.  Good luck on your journey. (But note VBA is no longer a supported programming language by Microsoft, so start learning .Net might be more futuristic thinking :-))